# Show the Boundary of a translation is the translation of the Boundary

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, geometry

Define the translation of a set $E$ as:

$$a+E=\{z\in \Bbb R^2: z=a+x,\text{ for }x\in E \} $$

I need to show that $\delta  (a+E)= a+ \delta E$, where $\delta$ denotes the boundary of the set. i.e all the points such that, if you form a ball around them, it intersects both $E$ and its complement.

Answer (score 0):

let $\tau_a(x)= a+x$ be the translation, note that it is continuous and 
has an inverse $\tau_{-a}$. Hence if $C$ is closed then so are $\tau_a(C), \tau_{-a}(C)$. Also note that $\tau_a$ 'commutes' with unions, intersections and complements.

Let ${\cal C}_E$ be the collection of closed sets containing $E$. Then note that
${\cal C}_{\{a\}+E} = \{ \tau_a(C) | C \in {\cal C}_E \}$.
It follows that $\overline{\{a\}+E} = \tau_a(\overline{E})$. Similarly,
$\overline{(\{a\}+E)^c} = \overline{\{a\}+E^c} = \tau_a(\overline{E^c})$.
Then we have
\begin{eqnarray}
\partial (\{a\}+E) &=& \overline{\{a\}+E} \cap \overline{(\{a\}+E)^c} \\
&=&  \tau_a(\overline{E}) \cap \tau_a(\overline{E^c}) \\
&=& \tau_a(\overline{E} \cap \overline{E^c}) \\
&=& \tau_a ( \partial E) \\
&=& \{a\} + \partial E
\end{eqnarray}